# Change multiple boolean columns' values based on a different columns values, using a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, boolean

There is a list of values

```
weather = ['cloudy', 'sunny']
```

I've got a dataframe with an old column "weather". We switched to 2 newer columns with boolean values, so all the old columns need to be accounted for.

Here is my dataframe now:

```
[In]
data = [['cloudy', False, False], ['sunny', False, False]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['old', 'cloudbool', 'sunbool'])
df
[Out]
     old  cloudbool sunbool
0   cloudy  False   False
1   sunny   False   False
```

Desired output:

```
[In]
data = [['cloudy', True, False], ['sunny', False, True]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['old', 'cloudbool', 'sunbool'])
[Out]
    old   cloudbool sunbool
0   cloudy  True    False
1   sunny   False   True
```

I know I could do something like what I've got below, but I've got a list of "weather types" much longer than 2.

```
df.loc[df['old'] == 'cloudy', ['cloudbool']] = True
```

I hope I conveyed that properly.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to create dummy indicator variables, then `join` it with original dataframe:

```
df[['old']].join(df['old'].str.get_dummies().astype(bool).add_suffix('bool'))
```

---

```
      old  cloudybool  sunnybool
0  cloudy        True      False
1   sunny       False       True
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I know that the `get_dummies` method is built for this, but another way to do this would be to create a series from list comprehension that compares the weather values in your `old` column to your `bool` column names (assuming they already exist as in your example). Then, covert it to a list in preparation for adding it to a datframe.
2. You don't have a direct match on the names, so I have omitted the last two characters, e.g. `cloudy` would be `clou` and `sunny` would be `sun`. I don't think any weather could have a suffix > 2 characters? Again this is why this wouldn't be as robust as `get_dummies`. You could also make your column names match your values, e.g. `cloudybool` and `sunnybool`:

---

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: [x['old'][:-2] in col for col in df.columns[1:]], axis=1).to_list()
df1 = pd.concat([df['old'],pd.DataFrame(s, columns=df.columns[1:])], axis=1)
df1
Out[1]: 
      old  cloudbool  sunbool
0  cloudy       True    False
1   sunny      False     True
```